# Can I charge an iPhone XS from my Macbook Pro 2015 when my MBP is running on battery?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, battery, charging

I'm certain I used to be able to charge my iPhone from my laptop's battery.

Yesterday when I plugged it in, the iPhone wouldn't charge from my laptop.

My question is: **Can I charge an iPhone XS from my Macbook Pro 2015 when my MBP is running on battery?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You can charge your iPhone via your MacBook irrespective of whether it is running on battery or power.

> Yesterday when I plugged it in, the iPhone wouldn't charge from my laptop.

It could be possibly be due to a faulty cable or port. Try cleaning the port or any dust or other accumulation and/or switching to a different port. You can also try connecting a different peripheral or device to ensure that the port is in working condition.